# Route with AngularJS 1.7.2

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

On the link below, I have an application with some route problem and I can't figure out why this is happen. I'm using Node.js to configure a http-server.

When I try to access `localhost:8080/#home`, nothing happens.
However, when I configure a "redirect to", the application open in a link like this: `"...:8080/#home!#home"`

https://github.com/tvbuosi/AngularJS

```
angular.module('meuModulo',['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
  .when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    controller: 'indexController'
  })
  .when('/contato', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/contato.html'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
  });
});
```

Comment: [post your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "some route problem" is not a problem statement. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: already edited the answer...

Comment: try accessing `localhost:8080/#!/home`

Comment: worked! srry about the stupid question